# How to pause and unpause the Particular action of a sprite?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d, cocos2d-x

My game has a sprite representing a character.  When the character picks up an item, the sprite should stop moving for a period of time.

I use CCbezier to make the sprite move, like this:

```
sprite->runaction(x)
```

Now I want the sprite to stop its current action (moving) and later resume it.
I can make the sprite stop by using:

```
sprite->stopaction(x)
```

but if I do that, I can't resume the movement.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
[yourSprite pauseSchedulerAndActions]
```

and to resume

```
[yourSprite resumeSchedulerAndActions]
```

Source: [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483487/how-to-pause-animated-sprite-animation-in-cocos2d)

If that shouldn't work, another option might be:

```
//pause
[sprite.actionManager pauseTarget:sprite];

//resume
[sprite.actionManager resumeTarget:sprite];
```

Comment: [yourSprite pauseSchedulerAndActions]
and to resume

[yourSprite resumeSchedulerAndActions]
These code pause all actions of sprite, i just want pause particular action of sprite, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, cocos2d-x has a built in way to do this. If you want to pause
   everything the character is doing you can simply use:

```
  _character->pause();

  _character->resume();


  _scheduler->pauseTarget(_character);

 _scheduler->resumeTarget(_character);
```

- NOTE: this also pauses any actions being performed on the character.
  If you want to continue the actions, but just pause the animation, do
  this instead:
- _scheduler is declared in the Node class, so all classes that inherit from it have access to it

.